# What's the MAPP protocol to fetch a posted transaction?

Tags: transactions, protocols, credit-card, specifications, modem

I've got some 15-year-old code that does MAPP (MasterCard Automated Point of sale Program) credit card transactions over [POTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) and a modem, with Host Data Capture (as opposed to Terminal Data Capture).  It implements:  get approval (opcode #08), post approval (#60), sell (#10), refund (#30), and void (#50) transactions.  As I recall, MAPP also allowed fetching the data for a given retrieval number or perhaps whole batches.  For validation purposes I need to implement one or the other (fetch a transaction or batch).  Fetching the card and amount for a given retrieval number would be sufficient.  However, I can no longer find our copy of "60-M08V3.0/1096 Point-of-sale Specifications and Certification Procedures", and that document doesn't appear to be anywhere on the web.  I'm guessing fetching by retrieval number would require something like TERMINALID, ASCII FS, OPCODE, ASCII FS, RETRIEVAL, ASCII ETX (or maybe the approval number is in there too).

What is the proper protocol to fetch (by retrieval number and/or approval number) a previously posted transaction or batch of transactions?  Is there a copy of 60-M08V3.0/1096, or the applicable portion of the protocol, somewhere on the web?

Comment: MasterCard Automated Point of sale Program

Comment: I suppose you don't have any paper document of the protocol. We worked with Point of Sale programs but I couldn't find this protocol in our docs. If you use a protocol perhaps you can find out how a request is build on the host program. Or get it from MasterCard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally finished working our way through the bureaucracy of the powers that be and found that current protocol documentation is available from product.integration@globalpay.com